# Why my firefox browser keep directing to a blank website with extremely long url after mouse clicking?

Tags: antivirus, malware

This is the link I encounter. I only extract a half part of the link. It's really long.
http://srv123.com/ads-clicktrack/click/newjump1.do?affiliate=64485&subid=024&terms=austin%20texas%20youtube.com%20video%20sharing%20camera%20phone%20
Why did I have this disturbing link? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have some spam-ware infecting your browser.

Run [Spybot search and destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/) and [Hi-jack this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/) to remove them.

Also uninstall any random software from your browser and computer.